# What are the zIndex stacking values of the <html> and <body> elements?

Tags: html

From where does the stacking count start in HTML? for the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.
I have seen many people writing `zIndex: -99` to bring the item to the back.

But if `z-index: -99` is possible, then what is the *static* z-index of the `<html>` and `<body>` elements?

Since the only reason we can't set the z-index on the `<html>` and `<body>` elements is that they're *static*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't exactly using the terminology that the spec uses however I guess you could say they have `z-index: 0` because if you set any child to `z-index: 0` it has the default stacking order, if you put a positive z-index then it will go above, and if you put a negative then it will be below.